Differnce between linux shell skript and Gitlab shell script
I have a pipeline that always fail with a shell command. This is:
response=$(curl -s -u "${HARBOR_SWIO_USER}:${HARBOR_SWIO_PASS}" -H "Accept:application/json" "$URL")

#This line will fail
echo "$response" | jq -e --arg TAG "$TAG" '.[]|select(.tags[].name==$TAG)' > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Image exists"
else
    echo "Image does not exist"
fi

I put this into a shell script on my Linux and execute it, works well. On Gitlab with a Linux Runner it fails.
I checked the jq version, both 1.6
I verified the JSON from response with JQ and this is successful (0).
echo $response | jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1  ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[1]}

But everytime the first call fail on Gitlab. Any Idea what is wrong?

Use if echo "$response" | jq -e ...; then directly, without trying to use $?; the if will cause errexit / set -e (turned on by gitlab by default) to be suppressed, but only for the condition it contains.

response=$(curl -s -u "${HARBOR_SWIO_USER}:${HARBOR_SWIO_PASS}" -H "Accept:application/json" "$URL")
#This line will fail
echo "$response" | jq -e --arg TAG "$TAG" '.[]|select(.tags[].name==$TAG)' > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Image exists"
else
echo "Image does not exist"

How does this answer the question?

I do not understand the answer, sorry.
